# TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined React Native Web

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-web

Friends I am just started with react native for web.
I am having the issues at navigation. When I am navigating from Emulator Android I am not having any problem with navigation. It navigate to Page2 at android. But When I open My localhost:3000 Web I am getting Error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined. Can any one tell me where I am going wrong. How it can be solve.

My App.js at location src/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {TouchableOpacity, View,Text,Platform} from 'react-native';
 class App extends Component {
//   OpenPage2()
//   {
//     this.props.navigation.navigate('Page2');
//   }
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
             return (
      <View style={{ backgroundColor : 'red',flex : 1, }}>

        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {()=>navigate('Page2')}>
          <Text>open  Page2</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

My  navigation.js file

```
import {createStackNavigator,createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import App from '../App'
import page2 from '../components/page2'
//import {name as appName} from './app.json';
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    App :{screen : App},
    Page2:{screen : page2},
})

const app = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);


//AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
export default app;
```

Comment: Can you check this https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-react-native-web-app-a-happy-struggle-aea7906f4903

Comment: Welcome, write your correct answer to help other people who faced the same